# When should Sylow subgroups intersect and when they should not?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, inclusion-exclusion

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Prove that a group of order $11 \times 2^{10}$ has a normal subgroup.

And here is a solution I found to the part of excluding the case $n_2 = 11$ and $n_{11} = 1024.$:

Suppose that $n_2 = 11$ and $n_{11} = 1024.$ Let $\{H_i\}_{i=1}^{2^{10}}$ be the set of all $11$-Sylow subgroups of $G.$ Since $11$ is prime, if $i \neq j,$ then $H_i \cap H_j = \{e\}.$ This implies that $|\cup_{i=1}^{2^{10}}H| = 1 + 10. 2^{10}.$ Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be $2$- Sylow subgroups of $G.$ Since $(2,11) = 1,$ this implies that $K_i \cap H_j = \{e\}.$ Since $K_1$ and $K_2$ are distinct subgroups, $|K_1 \cap K_2| > 1$ which implies $|K_1 \cup K_2| \geq 2^{10} + 1.$ This implies $|K_1 \cup K_2 \cup (\cup_{i=1}^{2^{10}} H_i)| \geq 1 + 10.2^{10} + 2^{10} = 1 + 11. 2^{10} > |G|.$ This is a contradiction.

Still I do not understand why the $2$- Sylow subgroups have a non-trivial intersection i.e., why $|K_1 \cap K_2| > 1$ while the $11$- Sylow subgroups has a trivial intersection $H_i \cap H_j = \{e\}$? could someone explain this to me, please?

Note that: I have read these questions

1 - [When is the intersection between two Sylow subgroups trivial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060477/when-is-the-intersection-between-two-sylow-subgroups-trivial)
2- [Any group of order $12$ must contain a normal Sylow subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549806/any-group-of-order-12-must-contain-a-normal-sylow-subgroup?rq=1)

But still I do not understand the reason in my case.

Comment: Are you sure that in the solution there is $|K_1 \cap K_2| > 1$ and not something similar, e.g. $|K_1 \Delta K_2| \geqslant 1$? Because as it is, indeed it is dubious.

Comment: Every element of $H_j$ exculding $e$ generates $H_j$. Thus, $H_i\cap H_j=\{e\}$.

Comment: If $K_1\cap K_2=\{e\}$, then your group contains at least $1+10\cdot 2^{10}+2(2^{10}-1)$ elements.

Comment: @Adayah yes I am sure

Comment: @richrow are you saying that whether they intersect trivially or non-trivially we will arrive at a contradiction also?

Comment: Also, I do not understand how you get the term $2(2^{10} - 1),$ could you please explain this more? and why if they do not intersect trivially, we will have $2^{10} + 1$ instead? @richrow

Comment: The claim that $|K_1\cap K_2|\gt 1$ is completely irrelevant and unnecessary here. All you need is that $K_1\cup K_2$ has strictly more than $2^{10}+1$ elements, and this holds whether the intersection is trivial or nontrivial; it follows from $K_1\neq K_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $11$-Sylow subgroups are groups of order $11$. If $H$ is a group of prime order, then it has no proper nontrivial subgroup; in particular, since distinct $p$-Sylow subgroups cannot contain each other, the intersection of two distinct Sylow subgroups of prime order must be trivial. So the intersection of any two $11$-Sylow subgroups, which are each of prime order, must be trivial.

That means that each element of order $11$ is in one and only one $11$-Sylow subgroup (each one is definitely in at least one, but no two distinct ones have nontrivial elements in common). How many elements do the $n_{11}=2^{10}$ subgroups account for? Each one has $10$ elements of order $11$ and one element of order $1$; the element of order $1$ is common to all of them. The rest are all distinct. So that accounts for $n_{11}(10) + 1 = 2^{10}(10)+1$ elements of the group $G$.

Now, you cannot argue the same way with the $2$-Sylow subgroups, since they aren't of prime order. But suppose first that any two $2$-Sylow subgroups have trivial intersection (that *could* happen). Then each of them has $2^{10}$ elements, and no non-identity element is in two or more of them. So this accounts for $n_2(2^{10}-1) + 1$ elements: $2^{10}-1$ nontrivial elements in each of the $n_2$ subgroups, plus the identity. This would give a further $11(2^{10}-1)$ elements, plus the identity (which we already counted).

So if we have both $2^{10}$ $11$-Sylow subgroups, and $11$ $2$-subgroups, *and* any two $2$-Sylow subgroups have trivial intersection, then this would account for
$$2^{10}(11-1) + 11(2^{10}-1) + 1 = 21(2^{10}) - 10 = 11\times 2^{10} + 10(1023)\gt 11\times 2^{10}\text{ elements.}$$
As this is more than the total number of elements that we have in $G$, our assumptions cannot all hold.

The last unwarranted assumption we made was that any two of the $2$-Sylow subgroups intersect trivially. So we should assume that if $n_{11}=2^{10}$ and $n_2=11$, then there are two Sylow $2$-subgroups, call them $K_1$ and $K_2$, such that $K_1\cap K_2\neq\{e\}$. Proceed from there.

Comment: But we always considered 2 as a prime number in my previous studies, but now you are telling me that $2$ is not prime, right?

Comment: @Brain: What? Where exactly did I say, imply, insinuate, or in any way treat $2$ as something other than a prime number?

Comment: Ohhh my bad ... sooorry ..... yes they are not of prime order ... you are correct.

Comment: Then I should count the number of elements if the intersection is nontrivial ..... should I the exclusion inclusion principle or use the same way you counted? could you give me a hint about counting in this case please?

Comment: @Brain: Then you can continue following the argument you posted. I've answered the question you posted: why are the intersections of any two $11$-Sylow subgroups trivial, and why, under the given assumptions, do we assume that there are two $2$-Sylow subgroups with nontrivial intersection? You already have an argument in front of you to continue from that point. Don't use a comment thread to try to ask additional questions in a single post.

Comment: Ok, thank you :)